# How to query dates in MongoDB using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, date

I have the following `MongoDB`data:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ae..."),
  "name": "John",
  "startdate": ISODate("2018-05-10T00:00:00Z"),
  "enddate": ISODate("2018-05-12T00:00:00Z")
}
```

I'm trying to query by typing the period in a form, expecting to get the result by the following logic:
`startdate`<= the typed end date AND `enddate` >= the typed initial date.

I send the typed dates by `ajax` using the following format: "YYYY-MM-DD".

In `PHP`, I try this:

```
$initialdate = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDatetime(strtotime($_POST['startdate'] . " 00:00:00"));
$enddate = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDatetime(strtotime($_POST['enddate'] . " 00:00:00"));
```

And then I try this query:

```
$query = ['startdate' => ['$lte' => $initialdate], 'enddate' => ['$gte' => $enddate]];
```

Unfortunattely I get no results.

How can I execute this query correctly?

Comment: The [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function returns "seconds since epoch" where the [`UTCDateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php) function expects "milliseconds since epoch".  You need to multiply by `1000` to get the correct date value `UTCDateTime(strtotime($_POST['startdate'] . " 00:00:00")*1000)`